# Proving $n^2$ is even whenever $n$ is even via contradiction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to understand the basis of contradiction and I feel like I have understood the ground rules of it.

For example: Show that the square of an even number is an even number using a contradiction proof.

What I have is: Let `n` represent the number.

`n` is odd if `n = 2k + 1`, where `k` is any number

`n` is even if `n = 2k`, where `k` is any number

We must prove that if `n^2` is even, then `n` is even.

How do I proceed on from here?

Comment: You have already posted a question about this not too long ago.

Comment: Hint: directly plug in $2k+1$ for $n$ then see that you receive a contradiction.  You want to assume $n^2$ is odd for contradiction.

Comment: @Sentrl,you are welcome,please look on my answer,you simple should assume contradiction and you  will see  by this step  how to apply  this emthod

Answer (score 2):

We prove the [contrapositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).  In this case, we want to prove

> $n^2$ even implies $n$ even

which is equivalent to the contrapositive

> $n$ not even implies $n^2$ not even

or in other words

> $n$ odd implies $n^2$ odd.

If $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$ then
\begin{align*}
n^2 &= (2k+1)^2 & \text{substituting in } n=2k+1 \\
 &= 4k^2+4k+1 & \text{expanding} \\
 &= 2(2k^2+2k)+1
\end{align*}
which is odd, since it has the form $2M+1$.

We can essentially turn this into a proof by contradiction by beginning with "If $n$ is odd and $n^2$ is even...", then writing "...giving a contradiction" at the end.  Although this should be regarded as unnecessary.

---

The other direction, i.e.,

> $n$ even implies $n^2$ even

can also be shown in a similar way:  If $n=2k$, then $n^2=(2k)^2=4k^2=2(2k^2)$ which is even.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist by contradiction...then consider some $n$ that is even, then:
$$n = 2k$$
Where $k$ is some natural number not $0$. Assume that $n^2$ is not even, but then contradicting the fact that $n^2 = (2k)^2 = 4k^2 = 2(2k^2)$ is even.

Alternatively, if $n^2$ is even but $n$ is odd, then $n = 2k+1$ so $$(2k+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 = 2(2k^2 + 2k) + 1$$
...contradicting the fact that $n^2$ is assumed to be even.